# Member dues report

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

CiviCRM 4.6.8 and WP4.3
I have Memberships setup with a main membership and chapter memberships.  When a person buys a Main Membership and Chapter Membership with one payment I can not report on the Chapter Member only.  It gives me the amount for the full payment.  When I look at the detail I can see the items for the payment.  How can I report on just the Chapter payment?   I can get just the Chapters but it shows the full payment.  Again, I need just the Chapter amount.

Comment: Gary - are you using a Price Set?

Comment: Yes.. using a Price Set.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using price set then you might find this [blog](https://civicrm.org/blogs/eileen/getting-data-out-civi-extending-reports) and the [extended reports extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) useful

Comment: +1 for the Extended Reports extension, this will give you what you need.  This allows reporting (though not searching) based on the line items rather than the contribution.  There's also a rumor that the Botanical Society has an extension that allows searching on the line items...

Comment: Ok.  Already have the Extended Report Ext loaded and the Export to Excel loaded.  I WILL dig deeper.

Comment: I can not get the field called "Item"  The Extended Report shows Qty Unit Price, Total Price but I can not find the Item.  Any way to get the Item listed in the report?

Comment: I AM WILLING TO PAY SOMEONE BECAUSE I HAVE TO GET THIS DONE!  Please email me directly if you can help!   Along with above here's what I have and then need.   
HAVE: I do use a price set.  Once the Membership(s) are created and you go into the Individual Contact Membership Tab and Edit the membership and then edit the Related Payments at the top I will see the two line items with the Item, Qty, Unit Price, Total Price.  I MUST be able to search on the Line Item Des

Comment: A sample of my data is "Chapter Dues - Pennsylvania-Delaware"  
Using the Extended Reports Extension I can get the numerical values ok but the Item Description is not available.  Is there a way to create a custom SQL Query somewhere for this?    I NEED a report that gives me all Chapter Dues filtered by Receive date and Price.